# How to use a function passed by a parent in a child component

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent which calls a child :

```
<select-school-type placeholder="Filter par type école" @selected="getSchools"></select-school-type>
```

I would like that the "getSchools" method is called when the user change the value in the component child. The getSchool method calls an endpoint with the selected value.

My child is :

```
<template>
    <select @change="onChange($event)">
        <option>{{ placeholder }}</option>
        <option v-for="schoolType in schoolTypes" :key="schoolType.id">{{ schoolType.id }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

And in my methods, I have this one :

```
onChange(event){
      console.log(event.target.value)
      this.$emit('selected')
    }
```

I see the console.log message with the correct value.

Bur after, how to call the getSchools method with the correct value ? I tried a lot of things without success.

I am a Vue beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass the value into the `$emit` method:

```
this.$emit('selected', event.target.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your child component, you have to pass the argument to the emitted string

```js
onChange(event){
  this.$emit('selected', event.target.value)
}
```